# Android LocationManager usando getLastKnownLocation() no se obtiene valor

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

Les hago esta consulta, inclusive antes funcionaba y creo (al menos creo) no haber borrado nada, pero dejo de funcionarme.

No encuentra la ubicación del dispositivo para guardar latitud y longitud. Los permisos en el Manifiesto están, ya les digo ayer me funcionaba y de repente dejo de hacerlo

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UltimoPaso.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 120);
    
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UltimoPaso.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    Log.e("Permisos: ", "No se han definido los permisos necesarios");
}else
{
    /*Se asigna a la clase LocationManager el servicio a nivel de sistema a partir del nombre.*/
   locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}

if (loc != null) {
   Log.e("Latitud: ", (String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude())));
   Log.e("Longitud: ", (String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude())));
   Log.e("Altitud: ", (String.valueOf(loc.getAltitude())));
   Log.e("Precision: ", (String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy())));
   latitude_string = (String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
   longitude_string = (String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
 }else {
   latitude_string = "";
   longitude_string = "";

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un error al capturar la ubicacion. No se guardo la ubicacion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Ingresa al `ELSE` es decir, que los permisos están, pero el resultado es que la variable `loc` retorna un valor `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que onda! no sé si lo que necesites es obtener la última posición conocida como dice el comentario anterior, pero te dejo mi solución para obtener la ubicación a través de la api Location. *Cabe mencionar que esto requiere que ya hayas implementado pedir permiso al usuario para obtener su ubicación*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Después nos aseguramos de implementar el metadata con la versión del playservices, obviamente debes verificar que lo tengas instalado en el sdk de android

[image: Play services instalado]

El metadata va a jalar solito el número de playservices no te preocupes de donde sacarlo

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Va dentro del tag `<appliaction>` muy importante.
Esto es todo en el Manifest

Ahora pasamos al gradle donde tienes que implementar el servicio de location. Hasta ahora esta es la última versión según la documentación

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

[Documentación para iniciar implementación de API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Ahora, en la clase debes implementar 3 cosas fundamentales

1. ConnectionCallbacks del GoogleApiClient
2. OnConnectionFailedListener de GoogleApiClient
3. LocationListener

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
       GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
       LocationListener

Al implementarlos también debes implementar sus métodos
onConnected, onConnectionSuspended, onConnectionSuspended, onLocationChanged

En el método onCreate() de tu clase debes iniciar la conexión a la api de google, para esto yo cree una función privada que lo hace de la siguiente manera

```
private void setupGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```

Además para llevar el control de la conexión, debes sobreescribir el método onStart y onStop de la actividad para conectar o desconectar de la api, así de sencillo

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

En el método sobreescrito onConnected del GoogleApiClient es donde el objeto de tipo LocationRequest será creado de la siguiente manera

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(2000);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,
            locationRequest, this);
}
```

En donde se pone que la exactitud sea alta (**LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY**), eso quiere decir que usará el servicio de GPS, WIFI y la red telefónica. Principalmente entender que cuando se busca una exactitud alta es por medio principalmente del GPS y eso requiere más batería (tenerlo en cuenta)
Si sólo se quiere un rango de exactitud medio o bajo se accede a los servicios sólamente de wifi o en su defecto de la red celular, pero eso conlleva a que varíe el rango de exactitud de 100mts a varios kilómetros, lo que no conviene si necesitas algo muy exacto obviamente. El intervalo en el que se estará refrescando la ubicación esta en función de milisegundos por ejemplo yo le puse 2000 que son 2s (**setInterval(2000)**).

Para el método onLocationChanged es donde vamos a obtener la Location como se muestra en el siguiente código

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cambio posición", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    locationTxt.setText(String.format("%s , %s", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()),
            String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())));
}
```

Simple y sencillamente el objeto location ya trae la posición y lo muestro en un textview donde se irá modificando cada que cambie por el rango de 2 segundos.

That´s it! happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

En este caso comentas que ayer funcionaba, veo que estas usando únicamente el proveedor de GPS:

```
loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

**Primeramente es importante verificar que tengas los servicios de geolocalización activados de otra forma no podrás obtener datos.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como tienes definido únicamente [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), debes asegurar que este activada la opción de "alta precisión", si no esta activada esa puede ser la razón por la que hoy no te funciona y `loc` tiene un valor `null`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Te recomiendo definir los siguientes permisos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

y requerirlos manualmente:

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted!");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    125);

        }
```

**Recuerda que el método [getLastKnownLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) requiere los permisos
[ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) para una localización aproximada y [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) para una localización precisa.**

Answer (score 1):

ya intentaste añadiendo el permiso de coarse location
de la siguiente forma?

`if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, 
     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
     ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, 
     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mContext,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                            100);
    } else
         displayLocationSettingsRequest();`